# ibpy : "Cannot assign to None"

Tags: python, ibpy

I freshly installed ibpy and have the following problem:

```
>>> from ib.opt import *
File "C:\Users\ME\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ib\ext\EReader.py", line 29
  from builtin import float, str, None, True, False
SyntaxError: cannot assign to None
```

Why it cannot find it? How can i fix this and download some price data?

Thank you all.

Comment: It seems that it cannot find the module opt at all. I get the following error:AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'opt'

Comment: Full Error message:                                           >>> from ib.opt import *
>>>  File "C:\Users\ME\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ib\ext\EReader.py", line 29
    from __builtin__ import float, str, None, True, False
SyntaxError: cannot assign to None

Comment: Ahh. That looks genuinely like a bug in the `ib` library, then. I'd suggest talking to its developers about it -- you might find out which specific versions of Python this release of `ib` was developed and tested against.

Comment: (I took the liberty of editing the full exception into the question).

Comment: Your file doesn't match the [latest version](https://github.com/blampe/IbPy/blob/master/ib/ext/EReader.py) - are you sure you installed a recent copy?

Comment: This is a [known and old bug](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ibpy-discuss/anvTSpEZ1-0/PCghinVZzpkJ)

Comment: You are right Eric. It was an old version and this caused the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by installing the latest version of ibpy.

```
https://github.com/blampe/IbPy
```